# How to convert non-numerical columns to numerical ones?

Tags: r, list, data.table, numeric

I am doing an essay for my PhD course, and I am having trouble with this question. I am going to send the part in which I have trouble and the whole thing.

```
 dt
                                  MC2                                        MC3
  1:                    It was in INR                          None of the above
  2:                    It was in INR                          None of the above
  3:                    It was in INR                          None of the above
  4:                    It was in INR                          None of the above
  5:                    It was in INR                          None of the above
 ---                                                                            
102: It was in USD (American Dollars) The foreigners were given a priority entry
103: It was in USD (American Dollars) The foreigners were given a priority entry
104: It was in USD (American Dollars) The foreigners were given a priority entry
105: It was in USD (American Dollars) The foreigners were given a priority entry
106: It was in USD (American Dollars) The foreigners were given a priority entry
     MC2_dummy MC3_dummy PPU1 PPU2 PPU3
  1:         0         0    7    7    6
  2:         0         0    6    5    5
  3:         0         0    7    6    7
  4:         0         0    5    5    7
  5:         0         0    5    5    5
 ---                                   
102:         1         1    4    5    4
103:         1         1    6    5    6
104:         1         1    3    3    3
105:         1         1    4    3    4
106:         1         1    1    2    2
> typeof(dt$MC2)
[1] "character"
> typeof(dt$MC2_dummy)
[1] "character"
> typeof(dt$MC3_dummy)
[1] "character"
> typeof(dt$PPU1)
[1] "integer"
> 
> typeof(dt$PPU2)
[1] "integer"
> typeof(dt$PPU3)
[1] "integer"
```

I tried this code:

```
dt = as.numeric(unlist(datatable))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I tried also a lot of other potential ideas that I saw on youtube:

```
cor(dt[sapply(dt$MC2_dummy, dt$PPU1, is.numeric)])
Error: 'dt$PPU1' não é uma função, caracter ou símbolo

dt = as.numeric(datatable)
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I am having trouble to convert this data into numeric. I am using data.table. Could someone help me?

Comment: `dt$MC2_dummy <- as.numeric(dt$MC2_dummy)` should do it.

Comment: Thank you, man. I am the whole afternoon trying to fix this thing.